# jquery conflicting with other jquery in page

Tags: jquery

I'm having a problem with some jquery conflicting with other jquery... can you tell me if i coded this right.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function(){
    var $mov=$(document);
      $mov.ready(function(){
    (".movie").mb_YTPlayer();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: have you tried http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Answer (score 2):

You can give this a try:

```
//Relinquish jQuery's control of the "$" variable.
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
  $(".movie").mb_YTPlayer();
});
```

Using [$.noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) will allow you use multiple instances of jQuery or avoid interference with other libraries using `$`.

It looks like you simply wanted to wrap `.mb_YTPlayer()` in a document ready. You were also missing `$` on `(".movie")`.

I'm not sure what you were trying to accomplish with `var $mov=$(document);`...

Comment: cool thanks that worked for part now i guess i have to find out where else it is conflicting

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery function returns an object, so your code is valid.  You can call jQuery functions on the variable within the variable's scope.

But I don't know what you mean by having "some jQuery conflicting  withother jQuery"